# cakephp input type number

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a mobile website form that I want to add type attributes to the inputs so that there correct keyboard format will pop up.

However in cakephp setting the type as number a textarea is created instead of the input and the type is not set.

Setting type as text does work.

How do I overide this and have cakephp just keep it as a text input with type=number?

```
<?php echo $form->input('phone',array('type' => 'number')); ?>
```

Result:

```
  <textarea id="UserCardExpires" rows="6" cols="30" name="data[User][card_expires]"class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"></textarea>
```

This is ok:

```
  <?php echo $form->input('postcode' ,array('type' => 'text')); ?>
```

Result

```
  <input type="text" id="UserPostcode" name="data[User][postcode]" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of the "phone" and "postcode" columns in your database?

Comment: They are varchar, users may include other characters in the form, so I am not strict on numbers. I jusr want the type set to number to bring up the num pad on the iphone

Comment: What happens if you do `$form->text( 'phone', array( 'type' => 'number' ) );`?  What version of CakePHP are you on?

Comment: Thank you very much that did it. I am using 1.3. I know that 2.0 has support for html5. If you want to post that as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On older versions of Cake, the Form helper won't automagically interpret `$options['type']` as the HTML5 input-element type attribute.  You have to force it by using "type" as an option on an explicit text element.

Use the following:

```
$form->text( 'phone', array( 'type' => 'number' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think phone numbers might be:

```
echo $form->text( 'phone', array( 'type' => 'tel' ) );
```

EDIT:

Sorry I'm an idiot, thats HTML5.